# Javee EJB workflow

Tags: ejb, workflow

Can anyone recommend a Java **workflow** engine that has good **EJB** integration?
By EJB integration I mean automatically deploying process definitions when the EJBs are deployed as well all the ability to call EJBs during process execution.

The reason I'd like to do this is to centralize workflow on the business layer and make it available to any component/application that needs it.

So far I have tried **Activiti** which has brilliant Spring integration but I struggle to get it to work in an EJB environment unless I embed it into a web application..

**JBPM** is another library I have some experience using but Im not well integrated it is to the EJB environment.

Any comments/suggestions are welcome. There are dozens of workflow engines out there so I thought I would ask more experienced people for their suggestions in addition to online searching.

Thanks